# Is every positive rational a sum of powers of every positive rational less than 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, power-series, rational-numbers, binary

Let $q,p \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ with $0<1-q \leq \frac{1}{p}$. Does it always exist a $c:\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ such that $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty c(k) \, q^k = p$$

If yes, is $c$ unique or are there many $c$'s for a given $(q,p)$? If no, what additional conditions need to be imposed on $(q,p)$ to guarantee the existence of a $c$ that satisfies the equality above?

Comment: If $p \gt \frac {1}{1-q}= \sum q^k$, then no such sequence of $c(k)$ can exist.  If $q = \frac 1n$ and the $n$-ary representation of $p$ can't be written using $0$s and $1$s, then no such sequence can exist.  For example, let $q = \frac 15$ and let $p= \frac 25$.

Comment: @RobertShore You are right thank you, these are both good observations. Is there a set of minimal conditions for which there is always a $c(k)$ that links $q$ and $p$?
More specifically, I was concerned with the case $q=\frac{2}{3}$ and $p=\frac{3}{2}$. Here I know that at least a $c(k)$ exists, but I would like to know more information about it. What about this case makes it possible for it to exist? Is it unique? Is it exhibitable? Is there a $j$ such that for all $k>j$, $c(k) = 0$? Or is it periodic maybe? Are there many $c$'s?

Comment: If $q=1/2$ and $p=1$ you can get the same sequence with $c(0)=1$ and all other $c(i)=0$; and $c(0)=0$ and all other $c(i)=1$.